# Proper use of new "container view" in XCode 4.5?

Tags: view, containers, preview, xcode4.5

I recently discovered the new "container view" in XCode 4.5 Developer Preview and wondered whether this is the proper way to use it:
[image: Two View Controllers, simply connected via button "Show View 2" and back button of navigation bar, both "embed" the small view below in their containers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Stanford IOS 6 programming course, 2013, on iTunes U. Paul Gregory, a superb presenter, gives a very good lecture covering the use of Container controls.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I watched his course back in 2012! He is a great presenter, indeed.

Comment: Is there a link to the actual lecture? Or the name of the lecture?